# Running current line of code in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am having an insanely annoying problem in python, which I will illustrate with screenshots of my output.

To preface, today Spyder 'magically' disappeared from my computer, leaving only its icon behind. I thought I was able to fix this problem by downloading anaconda and re-downloading Spyder. The app now opens correctly, but I am having trouble getting the console to run a selected line of code.

Now, when I am running my code, it takes two tries to get any output from the console, and once that bridge has been crossed, every time I try to run a specific line after that, on the first attempt, I get the output from whichever line I ran right before it. I do get the right output on the second try, but obviously I cannot really write/test my programs like this.

The above description is probably somewhat confusing, so I've included a picture to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening????

Comment: Strange... maybe you're having lots of lag or you have different python IDE running at the same time (they sometimes can fight over access to a file). Spyder generally has lots of bugs, but it seems running it in admin mode fixes some of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by some bugs in the Python console on Windows. Because of this and other errors, it's going to be removed in Spyder **3.2**.

Please use the IPython console instead.